# What is fault masking?

Tags: testing, masking, fault

Can anybody explain what fault masking is, and and what its consequences are?

Comment: have you tried using google? http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=fault+masking

Answer (score 5):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fault-tolerant_computer_systems):

> a way to ignore faults by seamlessly preparing a backup component to execute something as soon as the instruction is sent, using a sort of voting protocol where if the main and backups don't give the same results, the flawed output is ignored.

Imagine the five CPUs on the Space Shuttle, all crunching the same numbers. If one of them produces an anomalous result, that result is ignored. The other four CPUs "won the election" and "masked" (hid) the bad result.

Comment: I have a little knowledge about it...this is not i think is the right answer

Comment: @Guri: well, Google in general disagrees with you. What do you think it means?

Comment: @Michael, Sir what you are talking about is fault tolerance not fault masking?

Comment: @Guri: no, I don't think so. Fault tolerance might be the *tolerance* of errors, but fault masking is the *preparation* for the possibility of errors by preparing seamless backup.

Comment: @Michael:little bit i know about this is that it is error condition hiding another error condition...this is related to software testing

Comment: @Guri: you probably should have said that. Meanings change based on context. You should edit your question with that context.

Answer (score 1):

Fault Masking is an occurrence, in which one defect prevents the detection of another defect.

For instance, if you test a Login form consist from two data fields, "Login" and "Cancel" buttons, along with "Remember me" check box, when press "Login", an unhandled exception fires, so if the "Remember me" check box didn't work you will never know until a successful Login process has been done.

Answer (score 0):

Since you've tagged this as testing, this textbook definition might be what you're looking for

http://hissa.nist.gov/chissa/SEI_Framework/framework_17.html

> An acceptance test successfully masks
>   a bad value if a retry or alternate
>   results in a new, correct result
>   within the time limit set for
>   declaring failure.

Also see some discussion here but the final answer is not too clear as an example

http://www.geekinterview.com/talk/7964-fault-masking-is.html

Answer (score 0):

Fault masking is when the presence of one defect hides the presence of another defect.
for example:
 If the "Negative Value" cause a firing of unhandled system exception,  the developer will prevent the negative values input. This will resolve the issue and hide the defect of unhandled exception firing.